# Jquery Loading spinner/div (ajaxStart/ajaxStop) doesn't work on initial page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

I am using the following to show/hide a spinner on my page for ajax calls.

```js
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $loading.show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $loading.hide();
});
```

I have two select boxes. The 2nd is populated from ajax based on what is selected in the first.

When the page first loads, it calls ajax to start loading the 2nd select box. But on that first load it does NOT show the loading spinner.

When I then change the selections in selectbox1 AFTER initial page load,  the loading spinner works just fine. It works every time except on that initial load when the 2nd box is automatically populated when you land on the page.

How do I get it to spin on that initial page load while the 2nd box is calling ajax.

Comment: Is the first AJAX call made *before* you call `ajaxStart()`?

Comment: `var $loading = $('#loadingDiv'); $loading.hide();` and then your code should work I guess

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yup. That was my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You should provide an actual answer so he can vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rory McCrosson for the answer in the comment above.

I had the first Ajax call for the selector box loading before ajaxStart().  So I had to move my ajaxStart to come first.

Thanks!